# How do I publish a game written for Graal Online to Facebook?

Tags: publishing, hosting, graal-online

I made an MMORPG game using the Graal Online game engine. I hosted the game with their engine and servers, and it was fairly successful. Recently, they stopped hosting my game. The game is still fully functional, but with nowhere to host it, I am unsure of my next move.

The game was on Facebook before the hoster decided to not host it, anymore. We have 4,800 images for the game, 350 scripts that were coded in a language very similar to HTML5 and Java, and over 1,000 animations.

My goal is to have the game playable on Facebook and iOS/Android platforms. I do not know if I can use the old gaming engine or not, but I *should* be able too. If not, I hope that I still have options; I do not want to let all of this development go to waste.

How do I publish a game written for Graal Online to Facebook?

Comment: Please try to formulate a short TL;DR paragraph and your questions.

Comment: @Gnemlock the question is rather vague and broad. Hence my *comment* asking to clarify and focus ;-)

Comment: I am not familiar with GraalOnline. But am I right with the assumption that it relies on server-sided components which are not available to the public? If so you will likely not get around to port the game to a different engine. (please note that we don't do technology recommendations)

Comment: Phillip you are absolutely correct. Working on getting around this or using the server-sided components. If I'm unable to I don't know what to do with all of the images :[

Comment: I removed the overview and screenshots from your game. *It looks and sounds cool*, really, but all of that is completely irrelevant to the question.

Comment: I also removed the iOS/Android component of your question; publishing a game to Facebook is a differant ballpark than iOS and Android. As such, I would vote that a question asking about all three would be too broad. You say that the game has previously been hosted on Facebook, so let's start there.

Comment: Lastly, I feel this will almost *entirely* come down to someone having familiarity of the Graal Online engine. As such, I am making a tag for it, instead of *engine*, which we have blacklisted.